# Could you please suggest appropriate terms for the translation?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-choice, translation

I've been trying to translate some Chinese text into English with the help of google translate. Since google translate sometimes gives very poor translation, I would like to seek your help to determine whether the text is properly translated. The translated text is given as follows,

> Generally speaking, multinational companies have large production
> scales, and use international division of labor and **mechanized
> production models** to effectively control the production cost,
> production speed, quality and output of products. Therefore, the
> supply of products is stable, the quality is maintained at a certain
> level and there is room for price reduction. All of these are very
> attractive to consumers. On the contrary, the development of local
> enterprises in developing countries is not yet mature. The production
> technology, operating experience and **publicity ability** are
> relatively inferior. The product quality is relatively poor, **brand
> awareness is lacking**, and **attractiveness of the products is low**.
> Therefore, in the local market, industries in developing countries
> often lose out to external competitors and face the difficult
> situation of losing customers. **Their business space is narrowed.**

The terms in boldface represent terms whose translations I am doubtful about.

I have several questions.

1. Is the translation natural? Are there any improvements which will make the passage more understandable?
2. Could you please provide appropriate translations for the terms in boldface? In the following I will try to explain what each term means.

- mechanized production models: the use of machines to allow automation of the production process
- publicity ability: the ability of a company to promote its products among customers
- brand awareness is lacking: the brand is not popular and customers are not aware of the brand
- attractiveness of the products is low: the products do not appear to be attractive to the customers
- Their business space is narrowed: Due to the weaknesses of the company, the company can only do business with a smaller group of customers. The space in which the company is allowed to operate is narrowed.

Thank you.

Comment: Everything seems ok to me :D

Comment: Unfortunately, this is too broad (too many requests) and we don't provide proofreading (e.g. Is this correct? Is this natural?). We also don't provide translations, but there doesn't actually seem to be any here. Please focus on one problem per post and explain the problem in detail. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips and examples. See the [help/on-topic] for on-topic questions.

Answer (score 1):

The passage is fine.  I suggest minor tweaks as shown below:

I deleted the comma before the first 'and'.  The 2 phrases in [ ] can be joined by the 'and' without the deleted comma.

I added a few commas at the ** locations and also 'hence' on the last line.

'Marketing' and 'market' are terms you may want to consider.

My suggestion is

'Generally speaking, multinational companies [have large production scales] and [use international division of labor and mechanized production models] to effectively control the production cost, production speed, quality*,* and output of products. Therefore, the supply of products is stable, the quality is maintained at a certain level*,* and there is room for price reduction.  All of these are very attractive to consumers.

On the contrary, the development of local enterprises in developing countries is not yet mature. The production technology, operating experience*,* and 'marketing'/publicity ability are relatively inferior.  The product quality is relatively poor, brand awareness is lacking, and attractiveness of the products is low. Therefore, in the local market, industries in developing countries often lose out to external competitors and face the difficult situation of losing customers. Their 'market'/ business space is 'hence' narrowed.'